# The select control value not selected on modal binding in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, select

The select control value not selected on modal binding. Find html and controller code here... I have tried with track by "greedValuePercentage.Reference_Data_Code" but no use.

HTML:

```
<select name="valueBasis" 
 class="ContractSelectxs" 
 ng-model="subSection.Agreed_Value_Percentage" 
 ng-options="agreedValuePercentage.Reference_Data_Code as agreedValuePercentage.Reference_Data_Desc for agreedValuePercentage in vm.percentage.Reference_Data"> 
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
vm.percentage = $filter('filter')(result, { Reference_Type_Code: 'Percentage' })[0];
```

The model value from DB (assume that 20) -

```
subSection.Agreed_Value_Percentage = 20;
```

Comment: post your code properly

Comment: May you format the code and give more lines to help understand the situation ?

Comment: Now.. formatted correctly...

Comment: @user475391 its not even readable.